Azure DevOps Task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1 throws System.InvalidOperationException
Azure devops pipeline task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1 ran fine yesterday, but not today.
throws error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoMatchException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.GetComponentDetailsForDisplay(Alert alert) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 96
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.LogAdvSecComponentAlert(Uri baseAlertsUri, Int32 index, Alert alert, List`1 locations, String branch) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 47
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.Services.VulnerabilityOutputService.LogAdvSecVulnerabilitiesAsync(IEnumerable`1 alerts, String branch, GovernanceJobStatus processingJobStatus) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\Services\VulnerabilityOutputService.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.AdvSecOrchestrator.GetAndLogAlertsFromAdvSec(ScanResult scanResult, String projectId, AdvSecSubmissionArguments parsedArgs, String authToken, String repositoryId, String branchMoniker, Int64 sarifId, GovernanceJobStatus jobStatus) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\AdvSecOrchestrator.cs:line 220
   at Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection.AdvSecOrchestrator.ExecuteDependencyScanningAsync(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\tasks\dependency-scanning\detection\src\Microsoft.AdvSec.Detection\AdvSecOrchestrator.cs:line 148
Execution finished, status: -1.
Process terminating.


Can confirm, we are getting the same error :(

Also reported on MS Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/InvalidOperationException-in-AdvancedSec/10683049

Thanks for reporting this! I'm a PM from the Advanced Security team on Azure DevOps - we've pushed a fix and the dependency scanning task should be working as expected previously.

Thanks for your information. Testing on my side, the issue has been fixed.

Workaround: If your other tasks need to execute you can use continueOnError. This will allow the pipeline to continue execution even if the dependency scanning task fails.
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1
  continueOnError: true

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-task
Note: It appears as if vulnerable dependencies are still reported when the task fails.
